UVC Simulated Webcam Not Recognized as USB Device on Raspberry Pi Zero 2W
I am trying to create a USB device that can be plugged in to a computer and will appear as a webcam, but instead of having a camera, it will stream video from an MP4 file on the device filesystem.
The issue I am facing is the device is not showing up as a USB device when I plug it in to my Mac.
I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W. I have tried this on Raspberry Pi OS (Full and Lite) which is Debian Bookworm as well as on Ubuntu 24.10.
I have a script that is running and using v4l2loopback to create a virtual camera as /dev/video0 and I am binding the controller in the script to the UDC.
When I run  "v4l2-ctl --list-devices":
3f980000.usb (gadget.0):
/dev/video1
VirtualCam (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
/dev/video0
Once the setup is done, I run: "uvc-gadget2 -d /dev/video1 -u /dev/video0 -r 1 -f 1" (this is from https://github.com/wlhe/uvc-gadget)
Output:
uvc device is VirtualCam on bus platform:v4l2loopback-000
uvc open succeeded, file descriptor = 3
(continues running in foreground)

While the last command appears to be running, there is still no USB UVC device appearing on my Mac.
I was able to get this device to simulate a virtual ethernet adapter by loading g_ether in the /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt and /etc/modules and then rebooting the device and plugging it in. My mac saw it as a new USB ethernet adapter, so I know I am using a good data/power cable and the device is configured properly to be otg / peripheral in config.txt.
What am I missing here?
My script is below.
#!/bin/bash

# Variables we need to make things easier later on.

CONFIGFS="/sys/kernel/config"
GADGET="$CONFIGFS/usb_gadget"
VID="0x0525"
PID="0xa4a2"
SERIAL="0123456789"
MANUF=$(hostname)
PRODUCT="UVC Gadget"
BOARD=$(strings /proc/device-tree/model)
UDC=`ls /sys/class/udc` # will identify the 'first' UDC

# Later on, this function is used to tell the usb subsystem that we want
# to support a particular format, framesize and frameintervals
create_frame() {
    # Example usage:
    # create_frame <function name> <width> <height> <format> <name> <intervals>

    FUNCTION=$1
    WIDTH=$2
    HEIGHT=$3
    FORMAT=$4
    NAME=$5

    wdir=functions/$FUNCTION/streaming/$FORMAT/$NAME/${HEIGHT}p

    mkdir -p $wdir
    echo $WIDTH > $wdir/wWidth
    echo $HEIGHT > $wdir/wHeight
    echo $(( $WIDTH * $HEIGHT * 2 )) > $wdir/dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize
    cat <<EOF > $wdir/dwFrameInterval
$6
EOF
}

# This function sets up the UVC gadget function in configfs and binds us
# to the UVC gadget driver.
create_uvc() {
    CONFIG=$1
    FUNCTION=$2

    echo "    Creating UVC gadget functionality : $FUNCTION"
    mkdir functions/$FUNCTION

    create_frame $FUNCTION 640 480 uncompressed u "333333
416667
500000
666666
1000000
1333333
2000000
"
    create_frame $FUNCTION 1280 720 uncompressed u "1000000
1333333
2000000
"
    create_frame $FUNCTION 1920 1080 uncompressed u "2000000"
    create_frame $FUNCTION 640 480 mjpeg m "333333
416667
500000
666666
1000000
1333333
2000000
"
    create_frame $FUNCTION 1280 720 mjpeg m "333333
416667
500000
666666
1000000
1333333
2000000
"
    create_frame $FUNCTION 1920 1080 mjpeg m "333333
416667
500000
666666
1000000
1333333
2000000
"

    mkdir functions/$FUNCTION/streaming/header/h
    cd functions/$FUNCTION/streaming/header/h
    ln -s ../../uncompressed/u
    ln -s ../../mjpeg/m
    cd ../../class/fs
    ln -s ../../header/h
    cd ../../class/hs
    ln -s ../../header/h
    cd ../../class/ss
    ln -s ../../header/h
    cd ../../../control
    mkdir header/h
    ln -s header/h class/fs
    ln -s header/h class/ss
    cd ../../../

    # This configures the USB endpoint to allow 3x 1024 byte packets per
    # microframe, which gives us the maximum speed for USB 2.0. Other
    # valid values are 1024 and 2048, but these will result in a lower
    # supportable framerate.
    echo 2048 > functions/$FUNCTION/streaming_maxpacket

    ln -s functions/$FUNCTION configs/c.1
}

# This loads the module responsible for allowing USB Gadgets to be
# configured through configfs, without which we can't connect to the
# UVC gadget kernel driver

##########################
# RDS
# First, Unload existing video hardware
modprobe -r bcm2835_v4l2
modprobe -r bcm2835_codec
modprobe -r bcm2835_isp

# Then load the loopback as video0
modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=0 card_label="VirtualCam" exclusive_caps=1

# Ensure that video0 is there
ls /dev/video*
##########################

echo "Loading composite module"
modprobe libcomposite

# This section configures the gadget through configfs. We need to
# create a bunch of files and directories that describe the USB
# device we want to pretend to be.

if
[ ! -d $GADGET/g1 ]; then
    echo "Detecting platform:"
    echo "  board : $BOARD"
    echo "  udc   : $UDC"

    echo "Creating the USB gadget"

    echo "Creating gadget directory g1"
    mkdir -p $GADGET/g1

    cd $GADGET/g1
    if
[ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error creating usb gadget in configfs"
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "OK"
    fi

    echo "Setting Vendor and Product ID's"
    echo $VID > idVendor
    echo $PID > idProduct
    echo "OK"

    echo "Setting English strings"
    mkdir -p strings/0x409
    echo $SERIAL > strings/0x409/serialnumber
    echo $MANUF > strings/0x409/manufacturer
    echo $PRODUCT > strings/0x409/product
    echo "OK"

    echo "Creating Config"
    mkdir configs/c.1
    mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409

    echo "Creating functions..."

    create_uvc configs/c.1 uvc.0

    echo "OK"

    echo "Binding USB Device Controller"
    echo $UDC > UDC
    echo "OK"
fi



excellent idea! Finally, we can rickroll on a hardware level!
